# AutoDesk Forge Inventor - Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

```
[03/07/2021 07:14:00] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0
[03/07/2021 07:14:01] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[03/07/2021 07:14:01] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2020.3 (Build 243373000, 373) (24, 30, 37300, 0000)
[03/07/2021 07:14:01] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[03/07/2021 07:14:01]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[03/07/2021 07:14:01]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[03/07/2021 07:14:01] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening document: T:\Aces\Jobs\f4538135c02546e8871c3cf798795a13\input Invisible mode: False
[03/07/2021 07:14:01] Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
```

I get this error when running an AppBundle on AutoDesk Forge with Inventor.

Even when using the default AppBundle template straight out of AutoDesk's website.

Answer (score 2):

After two days of trial-and-error (it's not a helpful message at all), I found the reason.

**The Inventor File I was using needed a later version of Inventor than I had specified in the AppBundle/Activity.**

By default, the template configures for "AutoDesk.Inventor+24", whereas my file needed "AutoDesk.Inventor+2021" (a later version).

There was very little helpful information on the internet, so hopefully, this post will save the next guy some time!

Comment: Oh gee this answer is a life saver.